# Copy related rows from two tables into those same tables with new values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, "table1" and "table2". They contain rows that are related to each other. The table "table2" has pairs of rows with a column named "table1_id" and these pairs refer to the sequential "id" columns in "table1".

The task that needs to be performed is that I need to copy rows from both tables and put these rows into the same tables with new data while maintaining the relationships between them.

I have read several posts on StackOverflow and some articles on "mssqltips.com", but I am still not sure how I should do this. Should I use a cursor or a query with joins and a temporary table? What is the best-practice way to achieve the above task and if possible, could you demonstrate a short example?

Comment: You probably need to use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... table1 JOIN table2` kind of query. But it is better to show what did you already try so people can correct and lead to find a solution.

Comment: But that would not be sufficient to maintain the pair-based relationships between the columns. I can select, insert, and do joins all day long but this is a unique situation I have not encountered before. The problem is maintaining the relationship between the column in table2 and table1's primary key Id coumn.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "copy both rows from both tables and put these into the same tables" verbatim if the `id` column is being copied and is truly an ID (a unique key). If you want to duplicate some other (non-key) columns into new rows with new IDs, that's fine. If that's what you want, you can create the primary key (table1) row(s) first, and reference the newly created keys. How you do this depends on whether the `id` column is a generated or explicitly specified key, and whether you have any keys (primary or foreign keys) in `table2` as well.

It might look something like this:

```sql
insert into table1
select col1, col2, etc
from table1
where id = 'somekey'

insert into table2
select 'newkey' as table1_id, col3, col4, etc
from table2
where table1_id = 'somekey'
```

If you want to do this atomically, wrap it in a `begin transaction`, and make use of an `OUTPUT` clause or similar to collect the new IDs; see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) about that.

Comment: Note that no cursors or temp tables are required, although you could make use of joins depending on your schema and an `OUTPUT` could make use of a table variable or temp table if that's how you choose to implement it.

Comment: Thank you for your input. The "id" from "table1" is not being copied, they just receive a new value. The issue is that I need to "table1_id" column in the rows being copied from "table2" to match these new "id" columns from the copied rows in "table1".